# VBO action 'Modify OG user roles' does not show custom OG roles on the 'Add roles' list

Tags: organic-groups, users, 7

I have added new OG roles like 'tutor' or 'contributor'. I am using the view og_members_admin that comes with drupal commons, which uses view bulk operations 'Modify OG user roles' to give an admin the ability to add or remove certain roles. However, the only role selectable that I can add or remove is the default 'administrator member', despite the fact that I am user 1. Is there any further configuration that needs to be done to expose those custom added roles to that list?

Edit: when I try to add a user (through group/node/%/admin/people/add-user) the only role shown in there is also 'administer member', so this must be some site-wide configuration that is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that new roles are not visible to already created groups. When I create a new group I can see the added roles. However there should be a way to make existing groups 'see' newly added roles...